# How do you play a video on watchOS with resizeAspectFill?

Tags: ios, video, watchkit, movie, watchos

### Play video in your watchOS app.

[WKInterfaceMovie](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacemovie) — An interface element that lets you play video and audio content in your watchOS app.

---

Works as expected. Video plays. What about scaling it to **fill the screen**?

1. There’s a visual option in the storyboard. Selecting *Resize Aspect Fill* is ignored.

[image: Screenshot of Xcode]

2. There’s a function for that: `func setVideoGravity(_ videoGravity: WKVideoGravity)`

> The resizing option for the movie. For a list
>   of possible values, see the WKVideoGravity type.

---

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
    @IBOutlet weak var movieView: WKInterfaceMovie!

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        setupVideoPlayer()
    }

    func setupVideoPlayer() {
        guard let videoURL = URL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4") else {
            return
    }

        movieView.setMovieURL(videoURL)
        movieView.setVideoGravity(.resizeAspectFill)
    }
}
```

Basic setup in Xcode. Video loads on tapping the play button. Plays after loading. Doesn’t fill screen.

---

WKVideoGravity

Constants indicating the appearance of video content.

```
case resizeAspectFill
```

> Content is resized to fill the bounds
>   rectangle completely while preserving the original aspect ratio of the
>   content. This option results in cropping of the edges of the video in
>   the axis it exceeds.

That’s perfect. Let’s try it.

---

It doesn’t work.

Regardless of `videoGravity` (in storyboard or code), the video plays **resized to fit** and only fills the screen if I double-tap.

What am I missing?

---

Additionally, if I explore the `presentMediaPlayerController` method with Media Player Options, there’s an odd behavior I've noticed:

• `WKMediaPlayerControllerOptionsAutoplayKey` ✅

• `WKMediaPlayerControllerOptionsStartTimeKey` ✅

• `WKMediaPlayerControllerOptionsVideoGravityKey`  (Fails and falls back to default behavior)

Overall, it appears to be broken. I’d love a workaround if anyone has ideas.

Comment: Can you please share your code ?

Comment: Added code for context

Comment: @Zelko have you tried my answer. it works perfect in mine. refer this tutorial please      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyRdPUmhLtQ and https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Playing_Movies_and_Audio_on_watchOS_2_using_the_WKInterfaceMovie_Class

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Not yet… Maybe someday

Answer (score 0):

Apple APIs on the watch are buggy, this is clearly not working you can open a radar if you wish.

An alternative is to use a WKInterfaceInlineMovie ? you can format your video with desired aspect ratio (using ffmpeg or other tools), please see this code modified from Apple samples [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/WKInterfaceCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) .

```
class MovieDetailController: WKInterfaceController {
    @IBOutlet var inlineMovie :WKInterfaceInlineMovie!
    @IBOutlet var tapGestureRecognizer :WKTapGestureRecognizer!
    var playingInlineMovie :Bool = false

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        // Setup the `inlineMovie` interface object with the URL to play.
        inlineMovie.setMovieURL(movieURL!)

        // Provide a poster image to be displayed in the inlineMovie interface object prior to playback.
        inlineMovie.setPosterImage(WKImage (imageName: "Ski1"))
        inlineMovie.setVideoGravity(.resize)

        // Movie playback starts
        playingInlineMovie = false
    }

    @IBAction func inlineMovieTapped(sender : AnyObject) {
        if playingInlineMovie == false {
            inlineMovie.play()
        } else {
            inlineMovie.pause()
        }

        playingInlineMovie = !playingInlineMovie
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not set videogravity value programmatically. While they provide it in attribute inspector.

Set **Video Gravity** to **Resize Aspect**

Your attribute inspector should look like below snapshot.

[image]

And your code will be like below.

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
@IBOutlet weak var movieView: WKInterfaceMovie!

override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)

    setupVideoPlayer()
}

func setupVideoPlayer() {
    guard let videoURL = URL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4") else {
        return
}
    movieView.setMovieURL(videoURL)
}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but regardless of where it is set (Storyboard or code) things don't work.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, "Resize Aspect" is the default behavior. That works fine. The problem is with the other options, specifically "Resize Aspect Fill".